# Uncaught TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I'm trying to submit via ajax and I'm having some issues that I don't understand.

So I have the following function defined at the top of my main.js:

```
function formSubmit() {
  var valid = true;
  $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(index, el) {
    if(valid)
    {
      if($(el).is(':hidden'))
      {
        $(el).removeAttr('required');
      }
      if(!el.checkValidity())
      {
        valid = false;
        //el.focus();
      }
    }
  });
  if (!valid)
    return; // not ready to submit
  var options = {
    url:          document.location.origin + 'update.php',
    type:         'post',
    dataType:     'json',
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
    success:      showResponse, // post-submit callback
    error:        showError // post-submit callback
  };
  // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
};
```

Later in my main.js I have the following line that is run when I click a button:

```
$('#contact-form').formSubmit();
```

Also in my main.js I have:

```
$('body').on('change', '#contact-form', formSubmit);
```

In my HTML:

```
<form name="contact" id="contact-form">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" required>
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="contact">
</form>
```

When I run the `$('#contact-form').formSubmit();` line, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formSubmit is not a function
```

However, when I simply edit the name field (triggering the "on change" line) it updates and runs the function just fine.

What am I missing?

EDIT: It looks like the outcome I'm looking for is not apparent, probably because I'm not super familiar with javascript.

What I was trying to do was have a button that ran the `formSubmit()` function such that the `$(this)` element in that function was the form element.

I thought I could just run `$('#contact-form').formSubmit()` to do that but apparently not?

How would I go about running the `formSubmit()` function such that `$(this)` in that function refers to the element with an id of `'#contact-form'`?

Comment: Why do you expect  `$(...).formSubmit` to be a function?

Comment: formSubmit isn't part of the JQuery object so the error makes sense unless you are not showing us something.

Comment: Nothing specified, but `jQuery#submit()` does submit a form, maybe you want this method instead? And `jQuery#ajaxSubmit` might not be implemented too

Comment: @MikeCheel So how do I run the formSubmit function such that $(this) in the function refers to the form element? I guess thats what I'm really trying to do.

Comment: You could pass in the jquery object that represents the form element. You could find the form element from within the script (assuming it has access to the DOM). You could use function.apply or function.call to capture this. There are a number of ways.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('#contact-form').formSubmit();
```

With

```
$('#contact-form').submit();
```

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused. I'm mostly familiar with PHP so sometimes js can be confusing. However what I was trying to do was run the formSubmit() function I defined at the top with the form as the object calling that function. I guess More specifically I want the $(this) in the formSubmit function to refer to the form element

Comment: @KroniK907SO you bound the function to the submit event and than the submit() triggers that event.

Comment: @epascarello where did I bind the function to the submit event? or how would I bind it to the submit event? EDIT: Nvm... use .on('submit', ...)

Comment: @KroniK907: I guess the browser must be binding it through this line. $('body').on('change', '#contact-form', formSubmit). Now, that is not right either. It should be $('body').on('submit', '#contact-form', formSubmit);. Nothing in the jquery documentation says anything about using the change event on on a form element. Yet, it is somehow it is. I don't think it would would work on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try on submit.

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, try something like this:

```
+function ($) {

    $.fn.formSubmit = function() {
        var valid = true;
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(index, el) {
          if(valid)
          {
            if($(el).is(':hidden'))
            {
              $(el).removeAttr('required');
            }
            if(!el.checkValidity())
            {
              valid = false;
              //el.focus();
            }
          }
        });
        if (!valid)
          return this; // not ready to submit
        var options = {
          url:          document.location.origin + 'update.php',
          type:         'post',
          dataType:     'json',
          beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
          success:      showResponse, // post-submit callback
          error:        showError // post-submit callback
        };
        // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

        return this;
    }
}(jQuery);
```

That way, you should be able to use it like this: `$("#contact-form").formSubmit();`